# Normalize by Group

Tags: r, dplyr, normalize

I'm trying to normalize the StrengthCode by Item

E.g.

```
ID    Item    StrengthCode
7     A       1
7     A       5
7     A       7
8     B       1
8     B       3
9     A       5
9     A       3
```

What I need to achieve is something like this:

```
ID    Item    StrengthCode    Nor
7     A       1    0.14
7     A       5    0.71
7     A       7    1
8     B       1    0.34
8     B       3    1
9     A       5    0.71
9     A       3    0.42
```

I tried this code but I'm stuck.... if you can help me would be awesome!!!

```
normalit <- function(m){(m - min(m))/(max(m)-min(m))}

Tbl.Test <- Tbl.3.1 %>%
  group_by(ID, Item) %>%
  mutate(Nor = normalit(StregthCode))
```

I get this error:

> Warning message NAs introduced by coercion

Comment: I don't get the same results but the function works for me on the example data you posted

Comment: @Seb Do you have any group where the maximum and minimum value coincide?

Comment: Is `df$StrengthCode` a factor?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your desired output looks like you are wanting this:

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, text=
'ID    Item    StrengthCode
7     A       1
7     A       5
7     A       7
8     B       1
8     B       3
9     A       5
9     A       3')
df$Nor <- ave(df$StrengthCode, df$Item, FUN=function(x) x/max(x)) 
df
# > df
#   ID Item StrengthCode       Nor
# 1  7    A            1 0.1428571
# 2  7    A            5 0.7142857
# 3  7    A            7 1.0000000
# 4  8    B            1 0.3333333
# 5  8    B            3 1.0000000
# 6  9    A            5 0.7142857
# 7  9    A            3 0.4285714
```

With `dplyr` you can do (thx to Sotos for the comment+code):

```
library("dplyr")
(df %>% group_by(Item) %>% mutate(Nor = StrengthCode/max(StrengthCode))) 
# > (df %>% group_by(Item) %>% mutate(Nor = StrengthCode/max(StrengthCode)))
# Source: local data frame [7 x 4]
# Groups: Item [2]
# 
#      ID   Item StrengthCode       Nor
#   <int> <fctr>        <int>     <dbl>
# 1     7      A            1 0.1428571
# 2     7      A            5 0.7142857
# 3     7      A            7 1.0000000
# 4     8      B            1 0.3333333
# 5     8      B            3 1.0000000
# 6     9      A            5 0.7142857
# 7     9      A            3 0.4285714
```

Comment: Good catch. You should add the `dplyr` one as well to cope with OP's request (`df %>% group_by(ID, Item) %>% mutate(new = StrengthCode/max(StrengthCode))`)

Comment: hmm...that's strange, just group by Item then, not ID

Comment: Indeed... Friday is always a good day for these kind of mistakes :p

Comment: Man... ur awesome!!! TKS!! Saved my Friday now I can go to the party LOL!

Comment: @jogo any idea how this would change if `mutate_at` was to be used, such that each feature is normalized?

Comment: @MartinSöderström Something like `lapply()` over the columns with the normalizing function.

Answer (score 4):

Also easy to do in `data.table`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, Nor := StrengthCode / max(StrengthCode), by = Item]
```